# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'preprocess_input'

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, mobilenet

I want to try MobileNetV2's predictions. I always get an error message, but I don't know what to change.

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from keras.layers import Dense,GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.applications.mobilenetv2 import decode_predictions
from keras.applications.mobilenetv2 import MobileNetV2
from keras.applications.mobilenetv2 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import Image
from keras.optimizers import Adam

mobilenet = MobileNetV2()

def process_image(img_path):
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    pImg = MobileNetV2.preprocess_input(img_array)
    return pImg

process_image(IMG_PATH)
```

This is the Error Message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-6cdb09c1b552> in <module>()
----> 1 process_image('IMG_PATH')

<ipython-input-28-1b1187d4c25c> in process_image(img_path)
      3     img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
      4     img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
----> 5     pImg = MobileNetV2.preprocess_input(img_array)
      6     return pImg

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'preprocess_input'
```

Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Did you try `pImg = mobilenet.preprocess_input(img_array)`?

Comment: I can not see `MobileNetV2` having an attribute `preprocess_input` in the docs

Comment: Yes because `MobileNetV2` is a function of package `keras.applications.mobilenetv2` use `>> from keras.applications import mobilenetv2` then run `mobilenetv2.preprocess_input(img_array)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look in [keras_applications/mobilenet_v2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/mobilenet_v2.py) youl find that MobilNetV2
 has no attribute preprocess_input

you can import preprocess_input from mobilenet_v2:

```
from keras.applications.mobilenetv2 import preprocess_input
```

then you can use:

```
pImg = preprocess_input(img_array)
```